# magento2 installation error

Tags: magento2

[image][image: magento2 error]
when I installing magento2 the following error will have occurred please anyone can answer the following question

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just go to ***php.ini*** file of your server and uncomment(remove ; semicolon) following extensions

> extension=php_intl.dll
>
> extension=php_xsl.dll
>
> extension=php_soap.dll

and restart server .

Comment: ok thak you Mukesh Prajapati

Comment: ok mukesh prajapati

Comment: please see the uploaded picture i have only one error

Comment: @nukalasatish have you uncomment "extension=php_intl.dll" this in php.ini

Comment: from both php.ini

\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin

Comment: \wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12

Comment: Thankyou mukesh prajaapti its working fine

Comment: ok @ Mukesh Prajapati

Comment: @ Mukesh Prajapati please see i uploaded a pic . I have an error in after installation magento in admin panel

Comment: @nukalasatish write "localhost/magento2/index.php/admin_pdzd0o" and check is this working ?

Comment: it displaying 404 error

Comment: @nukalasatish ok check admin name i think something is wrong with path or name

Comment: ok @ Mukesh Prajapati

Comment: @nukalasatish just vote this answer so someone else can get help from this

Answer (score 0):

1. First, stop apache.
2. Edit `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`
3. Only **remove ;** at the begiinning of the line extension=php_xsl.dll
4. Only **remove ;** at the begiinning of the line extension=php_intl.dll
5. Then **start apache again.**

It will work proper

Comment: ok Ravindrasinh i tried but I having php extension intl error please see the above pic

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini

Are the Extensions only disabled?

If you have access to your php configuration you can change it for your self. If not you have to contact your host.

Answer (score 0):

Open your php.ini file and uncomment the below extensions by removing semicolon(;) from starting of the line and save the file.

```
;extension=php_intl.dll

;extension=php_xsl.dll

;extension=php_soap.dll
```

Then restart apache server. It will solve the PHP extension error.